# Access to react stack navigation inside header component

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

Inside the SamplePage, I could access navigation via `this.props.navigation`.
Inside the SampleHeader component, I have a button. 
How I can access navigation in `onPress` action in button, declared inside SampleHeader?

```js
  const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({    
        SamplePage: {
            screen: SamplePage,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'title',
                headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
                headerTintColor: styles.headerTintColor,
                headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
                headerRight: <SampleHeader></SampleHeader>
            }
        }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
   SamplePage: {
      screen: SamplePage,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        ....
        headerRight: <SampleHeader navigation={navigation}/>
        ....
      })
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and see if its works , you can pass navigation as props to SampleHeader :

```
const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({    
        SamplePage: {
            screen: SamplePage,
            navigationOptions: {
                title: 'title',
                headerStyle: styles.headerStyle,
                headerTintColor: styles.headerTintColor,
                headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
                headerRight: <SampleHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}></SampleHeader>
            }
        }
```

or you can create your own SampleHeader as that, and when you call it in a page suppose SamplePage you can add like,

```
class SamplePage extends Component {

render(){

return(
<SampleHeader navigation={this.props.navigation} />
)
}
}
```

and then after that , you can access on buttonCLick by this.props.navigation.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` at ` <SampleHeader navigation={this.props.navigation}>`